# How to write function where argument is type but not typed value?

Tags: f#, types

I want to convert a string representations of few dozen enum types to enum values.
It's easy to convert string to concrete type:

```
Enum.Parse(typeof<FontStyle>,"Bold") |> unbox<FontStyle>
```

but for now i want to write function where type and string are parameters.
The best one i can write is:

```
> let s2e (_: 'a) s = Enum.Parse(typeof<'a>,s) |> unbox<'a>;;
val s2e : 'a -> string -> 'a
> s2e FontStyle.Regular "Bold";;
val it : FontStyle = Bold
```

Is there any option to write something like this but with type itself as first argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function needs to take a single type parameter, which will be the type of the returned enum. However, you don't need to specify the type using a "fake" parameter that isn't used anywhere in the code - you can specify the actual type parameter when calling the function using the same notation as for example when calling `defaultof<SomeType>`.

The following modified function takes a single type parameter which occurs only in the return type (to avoid confusing SO code formatter, I replaced ' with ´ in the code):

```
> let parseEnum<´a> s = Enum.Parse(typeof<´a>,s) |> unbox<´a>;; 
val parseEnum : string -> ´a
```

When calling the function, you need to specify the type explicitly:

```
> parseEnum<FontStyle> "Bold";; 
val it : FontStyle = Bold
```

Your solution was pretty close to this - the only change is that you can specify the type parameter explicitly instead of providing a witness value to guide the type inference.

Answer (score 1):

Tomas's answer is good.  Additionally, note that you can apply F#'s `enum` constraints to prevent nonsensical type parameters from being used:

```
let parseEnum<'t,'u when 't:enum<'u>> s = System.Enum.Parse(typeof<'t>, s) :?> 't
(parseEnum "Class" : System.AttributeTargets)
```

Now calling `(parseEnum "Test" : int)` will fail at compile time since `int` is not an enum.

**EDIT**

Since we don't actually do anything with the underlying type `'u`, we don't need the full power of F#'s enum constraints, as ssp points out in a comment.  This is easier to use because it only has a single type parameter:

```
let parseEnum<'t when 't :> System.Enum and 't : struct> s =
  System.Enum.Parse(typeof<'t>, s) :?> 't
```

Note that the `struct` constraint prevents using `System.Enum` itself as the type argument.

Comment: It's really interesting, is there ways to say F# type system not to use dynamic downcast for such use cases? Using runtime cast is not the best thing for me, i suppose it's time consuming on large input stream.

Comment: Following variation of your answer allows to write thing a like ... |> parseEnum<SomeType>:


let parseEnum<'a when 'a:> Enum> s = Enum.Parse(typeof<'a>,s) :?> 'a

Comment: @ssp - There is no way to avoid the downcast (or an equivalent operation, such as unboxing).  The `System.Enum.Parse` method returns an object, so it must be dynamically converted to the result type.

Comment: @ssp - you're right that it's possible to use a simpler constraint.  I've updated my answer accordingly.